# 3 year Degree from India and 20 years experience

Tags: usa, h1-visa, indian-citizens

With 3 year degree from India and 20+ years work experience in Office Administration from Software company, Can I get  H1 visa.

Comment: Have you done any research? What have you found?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell if you *can* get it. You *may* be able to qualify for it if the 20 years of experience (with at least 3 of them after your graduation) are relevant to the position you are seeking, and the lawyers can write it up so that the USCIS will accept that in lieu of the missing year of education.